# Working with UWP MapControl and offline GeoServer tiles

Tags: geoserver, uwp-maps

I'm working with UWP MapControl and local networked GeoServer as my tile server.
When I'm connected to the internet everything works fine and the map shows my tiles.

When disconnecting the client from the internet the tiles are not visible.

Working with fiddler shows that applications sends request to ecn.dev.virtualearth.net.
When online, answer recieved and then sends requests to local GeoServer.
When not connected to web, no answer received and no request are then sent to GeoServer.

Is there a way to work disconnected from the internet? having an offline license?

Thanks
    Dror

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CustomMapTileDataSource for your use case. You can control making the request for the tile directly from your code (to a local or remote endpoint) and supply the tile to the map control. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.CustomMapTileDataSource

Comment: hi , i have encountered the same issue  , working with the suggested workaround causes some performance issue because of the need to convert the GeoServer response to bitmap, any other suggestions?

Comment: The overhead for converting a geoserver raster response to a bitmap should be minimal. How are you processing the response?